# The indicated ColumnName 'Data_Mov' does not match any column data source

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel, import

Trying to import some excel data to sql database, and they have different column names, cause the excel file has special characters and etc...
and I have always this error...

Here's the code:

```
    {
        string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);



        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

            String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=NO;IMEX=1;\"";

        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", excelConnection);


        excelConnection.Open();




            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", strConnection);

            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
        {
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Dado";
            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data_Mov", "Data Mov.");
            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data_Valor", "Data Valor");
            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Descricao_do_Movimento", "Descrição do Movimento");
            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Valor_em_EUR", "Valor em EUR");


            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        }
            excelConnection.Close();



    }
```

Error Line:

```
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data_Mov", "Data Mov.");
```

I Hope that you guys can help me

Comment: Is there a column named `Data Mov.` (with dot in the end) in the table?

Comment: In the excel table it is, but in sql you can't put that dot, that's why I want to match them cause my client want that "dot"..

Comment: Hava a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmappingcollection.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopyColumnMappingCollection_Add_System_String_System_String_). The first argument is the source column, the second argument is the destination column. Looks to me like you have them in the opposite order.

Comment: @user1429080 I already fix that, but thanks!